# Using scanner methods for simple Calculation in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a simple program that asks the user to input three items, their quantities, and prices. The program must allow the item names to have spaces. Here is my code that I have written so far.

```
   import java.util.Scanner;
   public class AssignmentOne {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

   //       System.out.printf("$%4.2f for each %s ", price, item);
   //       System.out.printf("\nThe total is: $%4.2f ", total);

    //process for item one
    System.out.println("Please enter in your first item");
    String item = kb.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please enter the quantity for this item");
    int quantity = kb.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please enter in the price of your item");
    double price = kb.nextDouble();




    //process for item two
    System.out.println("\nPlease enter in your second item");
    String item2 = kb.nextLine();
    System.out.println("\nPlease enter the quantity for this item");
    int quantity2 = kb.nextInt();
    System.out.print("\nPlease enter in the price of your item");
    double price2 = kb.nextDouble();
    double total2 = quantity2*price2;
   //       System.out.printf("$%4.2f for each %s ", price2, item2);
   //       System.out.printf("\nThe total is: $%4.2f ", total2);

    //process for item three
    System.out.println("\nPlease enter in your third item");
    String item3 = kb.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please enter the quantity for this item");
    int quantity3 = kb.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please enter in the price of your item");
    double price3 = kb.nextDouble();
    double total3 = quantity3*price3;
   //       System.out.printf("$%4.2f for each %s ", price3, item3);
   //       System.out.printf("\nThe total is: $%4.2f ", total3);


    double total = quantity*price;

    double grandTotal = total + total2 + total3;
    double salesTax = grandTotal*(.0625);
    double grandTotalTaxed = grandTotal + salesTax;


    String amount = "Quantity";
    String amount1 = "Price";
    String amount2 = "Total";
    String taxSign = "%";

    System.out.printf("\nYour bill: ");
    System.out.printf("\n\nItem");
    System.out.printf("%30s", amount);
   //       System.out.printf("\n%s %25d %16.2f %11.2f", item, quantity, price, total);
   //       System.out.printf("\n%s %25d %16.2f %11.2f", item2,quantity2, price2, total2);
   //       System.out.printf("\n%s %25d %16.2f %11.2f", item3,quantity3, price3, total3);

    System.out.printf("\n%30s", item);
    System.out.printf("%30d", quantity);
    System.out.printf("\n%30s", item2);
    System.out.printf("\n%30s", item3);



    System.out.printf("\n\n\nSubtotal %47.2f", grandTotal);
    System.out.printf("\n6.25 %s sales tax %39.2f", taxSign, salesTax);
    System.out.printf("\nTotal %50.2f", grandTotalTaxed);



}
```

}

My problem is that when I'm using String item = kb.nextLine(); here's an example of this process when entering the items

```
   Please enter in your first item
   soda

   Please enter the quantity for this item
   10

   Please enter the price for this item
   15

   Please enter in your second item
   Please enter the quantity for this item
```

At this point the first item is fine, but then it comes to the second item and it automatically inputs the second item line and moves straight onto the quantity, I don't understand how to fix this problem and I need to use nextLine(); so the item names can have spaces. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
  import java.util.Scanner;
  class AssignmentOne {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

   //       System.out.printf("$%4.2f for each %s ", price, item);
   //       System.out.printf("\nThe total is: $%4.2f ", total);

    //process for item one
    System.out.println("Please enter in your first item");
    String item = kb.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please enter the quantity for this item");
    int quantity = Integer.parseInt(kb.nextLine());
    System.out.println("Please enter in the price of your item");
    double price = Double.parseDouble(kb.nextLine());




    //process for item two
    System.out.println("\nPlease enter in your second item");
    String item2 = kb.nextLine();
    System.out.println("\nPlease enter the quantity for this item");
    int quantity2 = Integer.parseInt(kb.nextLine());
    System.out.print("\nPlease enter in the price of your item");
    double price2 =Double.parseDouble( kb.nextLine());
    double total2 = quantity2*price2;
   //       System.out.printf("$%4.2f for each %s ", price2, item2);
   //       System.out.printf("\nThe total is: $%4.2f ", total2);

    //process for item three
    System.out.println("\nPlease enter in your third item");
    String item3 = kb.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please enter the quantity for this item");
    int quantity3 = Integer.parseInt(kb.nextLine());
    System.out.println("Please enter in the price of your item");
    double price3 = Double.parseDouble(kb.nextLine());
    double total3 = quantity3*price3;
   //       System.out.printf("$%4.2f for each %s ", price3, item3);
   //       System.out.printf("\nThe total is: $%4.2f ", total3);


    double total = quantity*price;

    double grandTotal = total + total2 + total3;
    double salesTax = grandTotal*(.0625);
    double grandTotalTaxed = grandTotal + salesTax;


    String amount = "Quantity";
    String amount1 = "Price";
    String amount2 = "Total";
    String taxSign = "%";

    System.out.printf("\nYour bill: ");
    System.out.printf("\n\nItem");
    System.out.printf("%30s", amount);
   //       System.out.printf("\n%s %25d %16.2f %11.2f", item, quantity, price, total);
   //       System.out.printf("\n%s %25d %16.2f %11.2f", item2,quantity2, price2, total2);
   //       System.out.printf("\n%s %25d %16.2f %11.2f", item3,quantity3, price3, total3);

    System.out.printf("\n%30s", item);
    System.out.printf("%30d", quantity);
    System.out.printf("\n%30s", item2);
    System.out.printf("\n%30s", item3);



    System.out.printf("\n\n\nSubtotal %47.2f", grandTotal);
    System.out.printf("\n6.25 %s sales tax %39.2f", taxSign, salesTax);
    System.out.printf("\nTotal %50.2f", grandTotalTaxed);



}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using `System.in`, nothing is sent to the scanner until you've hit "enter". Meaning if you type "15" without hitting "enter", the `kb.nextDouble();` call blocks. When you hit "enter" then `kb.nextDouble();` reads "15", but there's still a newline in the scanner's buffer. That means this part of the code:

```
//process for item two
System.out.println("\nPlease enter in your second item");
String item2 = kb.nextLine();
```

Instantly reads the newline that was in the buffer from you typing "15" then hitting "enter". So it won't attempt to read an item name.

You can either replace all of your item name scanning from:

```
//process for item two
System.out.println("\nPlease enter in your second item");
String item2 = kb.nextLine();
```

to:

```
//process for item two
System.out.println("\nPlease enter in your second item");
String item2 = kb.next();
```

Or read the newline and parse the double when you scan for the price:

```
System.out.println("Please enter in the price of your item");
double price = Double.parseDouble(kb.nextLine());
```

Comment: @MarounMaroun No, if the item's name has whitespace (Scanner's default delimiter), then `next()` won't parse the entire line. If there's going to be whitespace in item names then that's not going to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
kb.nextDouble();
```

I need to check, but it looks likely that `nextDouble` leaves the newline intact which then is inputed by the consequent `nextLine.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem in two different ways:

- Replace `.nextLine()` with `.next()` in your code. (But doing this will not allow you to have spaces in the string.
- When you read a primitive and then you read a text, add another `.nextLine();` after it.

Using the second method in your case you'll have:

```
System.out.println("Please enter in the price of your item");
double price = kb.nextDouble();

String item2 = kb.nextLine(); // -------------> Added this line also here
//process for item two
System.out.println("\nPlease enter in your second item");
item2 = kb.nextLine();
```

Which will fix the first problem you have. Make the same for all other places, and your program will run as it supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

Either Use different Scanner Objects for getting String and Numbers. This solves your problem.